# Couldn't serve two Vue applications in a single container with nginx

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, vuejs3, nginx-config

I'm trying to set up an Nginx Docker container that serves multiple Vue.js applications. One of these applications is a login app, and the other is the main app. I want to route requests to the `/login` endpoint to the login app and all other requests to the main app.

**Problem:**

I have tried various Nginx configurations, but the login app is not working as expected. When accessing the `/login` endpoint, it's not rendering correctly, and resources such as JavaScript files are not loading properly.

**Setup:**

1. **Both Apps in the Same Container:**

   - Both the login app and the main app are in the same Docker container.
   - Both apps are built and located in `/usr/share/nginx/html` and `/usr/share/nginx/html/login`, respectively.
   - The Vue Router in the main app uses hash mode.
   - Nginx configuration for the combined container:

```
  nginx

      server {

          listen 80;

          server_name 0.0.0.0;

 

          location /login/ {

              root /usr/share/nginx/html/login;

              index index.html;

              try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

              expires -1;

              add_header Pragma "no-cache";

              add_header Cache-Control "no-store, must-revalidate";

          }

 

          location / {

              root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

              index  index.html;

              try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

              expires -1;

              add_header Pragma "no-cache";

              add_header Cache-Control "no-store, must-revalidate";

          }

 

          location @rewrites {

              rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;

          }

 

          error_page 500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

          location = /50x.html {

              root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

          }

      }
```

What could be causing the login app to not render correctly when accessed through the `/login` endpoint? Is there an issue with my Nginx configuration? Are there any specific considerations I should be aware of when serving multiple Vue.js applications in the same Docker container using Nginx?

Comment: Tried with url rewriting approach by adding this line in the `/login` location block.   ` rewrite ^/login(/.*)$ /login$1 break;`